# BlackBerry click outside Field

Tags: blackberry, imagebutton

I'm implementing a custom ImageButton for touch enabled devices (9500,9550,9800,...)
I have problem that click(touch) outside field generates event in focused field.(when extending `Field`, `BitmapField`)

I can solve it by moving focus to empty field, but this is not very nice.
Strange thing is that this behaviour is for `Field`, `BitmapField` but not for `ButtonField`.
It realy seems that when is `ButtonField` focused, outside clicks don't generates button event.

I tryed extending `ButtonField`, but I couldn't get rid of that stupid Button Background.

So my question; what is that difference in behavior between `Field` and `ButtonField` that causes generating events outside `Field`?

this is how I removed button background:

```
    // cahange button border
    setBorder(BorderFactory
            .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
    setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE, BorderFactory
            .createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a check in your touchEvent() for the ImageButton

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
    //make sure the touch is withing the bounds of our Field
    if(message.getX(1) < 0 || message.getX(1) > getWidth() || message.getY(1) < 0 || message.getY(1) > getHeight()) {
        return false;
    }

    //Do your work
}
```

The touch event is sent to the focused Field even if it isn't actually on the Field, you have to return false so the containing Manager knows to send it to the next Field that will accept it (the Field where the touch is on, or nothing if it is on empty space).

Edit:
To remove the button background, override `protected void applyTheme() {}`

Comment: yes I know about this check, but my question is what is the difference, and why ButtonField accepts only inside clicks? btw. in meantime I figured out how to get rid of button background, so now buttonfield works perfectly for me

Comment: @Janci can you please share how did you get ride of button backgrounds?

Comment: @TechnodHr I've updated my answer to show how to remove the button decoration