# BlackBerry touchEvent outside Field triggers fieldChanged

Tags: blackberry

I am having a problem where if i press/touch outside of a field the `fieldChanged()` event is triggered for the field that has focus.

The layout for my `MainScreen` is pretty straight forward, something like so:

```
public class myMainScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener{

    public myMainScreen(){
        CustomFM1 fm1 = new CustomFM1();
        CustomFM2 fm2 = new CustomFM2();

        add(fm1);
        add(fm2);
    }

}
```

If i press a button/field inside of either `FieldManager` it works fine. The problem is when i press on empty space. So if i were to press inside empty space in `fm2` and a `Field` inside `fm1` had focus, its fieldchanged event would be triggered.

At the moment, my remedy is to catch the `touchEvent` and pass it down to the appropriate `FieldManager`. The `touchEvent` for my `CustomFM` would then handle getting the field and calling fieldChanged, if a field has actually been pressed

So in `myMainScreen` touchEvent looks like:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message){

    int index = this.getFieldAtLocation(message.getX(1), message.getY(1));

    switch(index){

        case 0:
           fm1.touchEvent(message);
           break;       

        case 1:
           fm2.touchEvent(message);
           break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

And my `touchEvent` for my CustomFM2 is. 
`OFFSET` is the top y position of fm2, in relation to the screen.

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message){

    switch(message.getEvent()){

    ... 

        case TouchEvent.UP:
            int index = this.getFieldAtLocation(message.getGlobalX(1), message.getGlobalY(1) - OFFSET);
            if(index != -1){
                Field field = getField(index);
                field.getChangeListener().fieldChanged(field, 0);

            }

            break;

    }

    return true;

}
```

What I'm wondering is that if there is an easier solution to this? Am i missing something?

Comment: Can't reproduce it with 5.0 9550 simulator: 2 horizontal field managers, with click-consum button field in each. Works fine. click on manager's empty space does not fires FieldChangeListener event. Which version/device you're on?

Comment: @Max torch OS6. Think i got it figured out now though. the answer to  this post helped [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948222/blackberry-click-outside-field]. I'm gonna post an answer in a bit. what i was doing up above was a bit off the mark.

Comment: I had the same problem.

Please check answer here [BlackBerry click outside Field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948222/blackberry-click-outside-field).

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same issue. The main problem is that `navigationClick` and `trackwheelClick`  are called if the touch event is not consumed in `touchEvent`.

The solution is to call `fieldChangeNotify` within the `*Click` methods **only** if the click was triggered by a **non-touch** event. Touch events are given a status of 0 so you can check for that as follows:

```
protected boolean navigationClick( int status, int time ){

    if (status != 0) fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;  
}

protected boolean trackwheelClick( int status, int time ){        

    if (status != 0) fieldChangeNotify(0);
    return true;
}
```

This method means you don't need to track whether the touch event was within the bounds of the field.

Answer (score 2):

Seems what i was doing was a bit off. I didn't need to pass the event down. That is done naturally (or unnaturally, as the `Field` that has focus seems to be recieving `TouchEvents` event if it hasnt been touched). What seems to be happening is that after a `TouchEvent.Click` a `navigationClick` is sent to the field. In `navigationClick` i was calling `fieldChangeNotify(0)`

To fix this my `Field`'s `touchEvent` and `navigationClick` now look like this:

```
    private boolean touchEventInside;
    ...

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {

        if(message.getX(1) < 0 || message.getX(1) > getWidth() || message.getY(1) < 0 || message.getY(1) > getHeight()) {

            touchEventInside = false;
            return false;

        }else{

            touchEventInside = true;
            return true;

        }

    }

    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

        if(((myMainScreen)this.getScreen()).touchStarted){

            if(touchEventInside){
                fieldChangeNotify(0);
            }

        }else{

            fieldChangeNotify(0);

        }

        return true;
    }
```

I am also keeping track of touch events being started in `myMainScreen`, like so:

```
    protected boolean touchStarted;
    ...
    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message){

        if(message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.UP){
            touchStarted = false;
        }else if(message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.DOWN){
            touchStarted = true;
        }   
        super.touchEvent(message);
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is not to override `touchEvent(TouchEvent message)` at all. :)

Just override `navigationClick(int status, int time)` for the field you want to handle the click (just to be clear - no need to do this for `ButtonField` - it works nice as is). The BB UI framework will call `navigationClick(int status, int time)` when user clicks your field on a touch screen. As well it'll work for a non-touch screen devices.

Comment: yeah i tried that. Whats happening is that when i touch the screen outside of a field i get a `TouchEvent.Click` followed by `navigationClick`, which in turn is calling `fieldChangeNotify`. I guess its not happening on OS5 but it is on OS6 for me, on device.