# Touch event is not working

Tags: blackberry

I am developng one app for touch and type phone. Now in one screen of the application, there is 3 buttons.

Here if i touch in the three buttons, it is working. But if i touch outside the buttons, means in the top bar or in the bottom bar, then also touch event is working. Suppose in the below, Add More button is focused. So if i am touching in the bottom bar, then also button touch is working. To resolve this problem, i wrote the below code:

```java
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent event) {
    try {

        int touchXPos = event.getX(1);
        int touchYPos = event.getY(1);
        int addBtnXPos = btnAddMore.getLeft();
        int saveBtnXPos = btnSave.getLeft();
        int helpBtnXpos = btnHelp.getLeft();

        int vfmTitleTouch = m_vfmTitle.getHeight();
if(event.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK)
      {
        if ((touchXPos >= addBtnXPos + 40) && (touchXPos <= (addBtnXPos + btnAddMore.getWidth() + 40)) && (touchYPos <= screenHeight -10) && (touchYPos >= (screenHeight -10 - btnAddMore.getHeight())) /*&& (touchYPos < (screenHeight-gmYPos)) */) {
            Logger.out("touchEvent", "------------------------------1");
            showPopUp();

        } else if ((touchXPos >= saveBtnXPos + 40) && (touchXPos <= (saveBtnXPos + 40 + btnSave.getWidth())) && (touchYPos <= screenHeight -10) && (touchYPos >= (screenHeight -10 - btnSave.getHeight())) /* && (touchYPos < (screenHeight-gmYPos))*/) {
            Logger.out("touchEvent", "------------------------------2");
            saveToDb();

        } else if ((touchXPos >= helpBtnXpos) && (touchXPos <= (helpBtnXpos + btnHelp.getWidth())) && (touchYPos <= (btnHelp.getTop() + btnHelp.getHeight())) && (touchYPos >= btnHelp.getTop()) /* && (touchYPos < (screenHeight-gmYPos))*/ ) {
            Logger.out("touchEvent", "------------------------------3");
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new HelpScreen());

        } else if ((touchYPos <= screenHeight - hfmBtn.getHeight()) && (touchYPos >= (vfmTitleTouch))) {
            Logger.out("touchEvent", "------------------------------4");
            //Logger.out("touchEvent", "touchY::::" +touchYPos  + "Vfm Title::::" +vfmTitleTouch  + "  "+"GM Y Pos"+  gmYPos);

        } 
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return super.touchEvent(event);
}
```

But it is not working..Can any one help me out??
And touch event should work in the middle of the screens like for check boxes also..

Thanks..[image: This is the screen shot of the screen]

Answer (score 2):

Check the answers of the question [BlackBerry touchEvent outside Field triggers fieldChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398282/blackberry-touchevent-outside-field-triggers-fieldchanged) provided by [Paul Sylliboy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418301/431639) and [Arhimed](http://ttp://stackoverflow.com/a/6422582/431639).

I have pasted those links on comment first, but later removed it from there to share the code snippet for killing unwanted touch events, which I found very useful.

```java
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
    int event = message.getEvent();
    // you can add other events 
    if (event == TouchEvent.CLICK || event == TouchEvent.UNCLICK) {
        // Kill all click events that happen outside any fields
        if (getFieldAtLocation(message.getX(1), message.getY(1)) == -1)         
            return true;
    }

    return super.touchEvent(message);
}

// The regular getFieldAtLocation returns wrong values in 
// open spaces in complex managers, so we override it
public int getFieldAtLocation(int x, int y) {
    XYRect rect = new XYRect();
    int index = getFieldCount() - 1;
    while (index >= 0) {
        getField(index).getExtent(rect);
        if (rect.contains(x, y))
            break;
        --index;
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rupak. I also made some changes in the code. But it is somehow working. Now when i am clicking outside the button, it is not executing the code related to button, but focus is only coming to the button. It means when i ma touching outside the save button, focus is coming to the save button.

Comment: I have a simple query. Did you set any `FieldChangeListener` for those `ButtonField`s? If yes then you dont't have to do anything in `touchEvent(..)` except killing unwanted events. And I'm not sure about what may cause the focus problem. You can follow the strategy described in the answer link provided above.

Comment: So you mean i should not use both: FieldChangeListeer and touchevent()?

Comment: Yes, because normally the parent Field/Manager/Screen handles all the touch events and It will eventually pass the event to the `fieldChanged(...)` method.

Comment: if i will write your code that you posted, then also it is giving the same problem...