# TouchEvent() and FieldChange() in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, touch-event

I am working with 2 resolutions one touchScreen and other Non- touch

i have designed a Screen which has 10 custombuttons  are added to a VerticalFieldManager
The CustomButtonField  class extends Field class

i have used 2 methods fieldChange() and touchEvent() for touchScreens
the problem is whenever i do click on button it gets activated correctly for touchevent()
but then the fieldChange() method also gets called immediately afterwards

what should i do??
what's the problem ??

Comment: I am familiar to this concept but I think onTouchEvent() will be working good for its term but when the focus get off from a click button it automatically makes a event i.e. FieldChange(). This is just what i guess is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answers of the question [BlackBerry touchEvent outside Field triggers fieldChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398282/blackberry-touchevent-outside-field-triggers-fieldchanged) provided by [Paul Sylliboy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6418301/431639) and [Arhimed](http://ttp://stackoverflow.com/a/6422582/431639).

In those answers, there was a method which only updates a `boolean` variable to identify that a touch event occured, and based on the value of that `boolean` an action is executed on the `fieldChanged` or `navigationClick` method.

> BB UI Framework calls `navigationClick(int status, int time)`
>   automatically if there is any touch event after execution of
>   `protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)`. And
>   `navigationClick(int status, int time)` calls the method
>   `fieldChangeNotify(0)` which causes `fieldChange()` (in the question)
>   or `public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`  to be called.